# Design preview not showing any device options

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I am using Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2 version and I cannot get the design preview to show. There are no devices available in the dropdown. I have tried adding a new device definition.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was in the `gradle` file. Once I updated the `build tools version` the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

> i think you need to update your sdk with another APIs

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem was with build tools version being out of sync. I have resolved it now.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code in your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I managed to fix the problem by updating the build tools version in the end.